# Will placing custom templates in sub directory break any native WordPress functionality

Tags: templates, page-template, directory

I have, on an existing project, created a folder named `templates` in the theme root directory where I have put all my custom template files, all the files that have the `Template Name: BlahBlahBlah` in the top of the file.

This change broke places in the code where I had done this to get the file name:
`get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );`.

I fixed it like this: `basename(get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true ));`.

My question is if I broke something in WordPress by doing this change.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WP 3.4 page templates can be stored in theme root folder or direct sub-directoryr, that is no problem. But rename page templates, which include moving files to other directories, will unassign that page templates for all pages currently using it.

To reassign the page template, simply edit the page, and reselect the desired template.

About the `get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );`, if the template file is under "mytheme/sub-dir/templae-file.php", the `_wp_page_template` value should be "sub-dir/template-fie.php". Using `basename` leave only "template-fie.php"; you may have reasons to need only the name of the file but it is not the correct value for `_wp_page_template`, so it is not broken.

Comment: Thanks! I use the filename to check for a specific file. I could always check on the whole path. The reason I do this is because I have a plug-in I only want on certain pages. Doing it this way works, but seems kinda shady.